# fetch only particular data from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database, nspredicate

I am using firebase in my swift 2 project.

```
{
   'Registration'
     {
    'SomerandomkeyofuserID':
        {
        'Car':
            {
            'random key 1':
                {
                'name': 'Chris';
                'date': '24 May 2016'
                }
            'random key 2':
                {
                'name': 'John';
                'date': '25 May 2016'
                }
            'random key 3':
                {
                'name': 'Chris';
                'date': '24 May 2016'
                }
            'random key 4':
                {
                'name': 'John';
                'date': '25 May 2016'
                }

        }
}
```

I want to fetch the snapshot of data only which have 'name' = 'john'

I am using below code.But it gives me all the 4 data.

```
let userRef = dataBaseRef.child("Registration/").child((FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser?.uid)!).child("Car")

let userRef1 =  userRef.queryOrderedByChild("car_name")

userRef1.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    print("SNAPSHOT: ",snapshot.childrenCount)
    print("SNAPSHOT: ",snapshot)

)}
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you indexed the data in your rules? Other thing, you want to fetch it by name, but you observe car_name, how is this?

Answer (score 3):

Change your userRef1 reference to something like:

```
let userRef1 =  userRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: "John")
```

This should work.

Also remember you will need to [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) your data.